# Syntax error in Insert query in Mysql in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am doing project in VB.NET and backend is mysql

Can you please tell me where the error is occured

```
Public Sub ins()
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd1 As New OdbcCommand("insert into party values('" + pcode_txt.Text + "','" + Trim(UCase(name_txt.Text)) + "','" + Trim(UCase(addr_txt.Text)) + "','" + phone_txt.Text + "','" + combo_route.SelectedItem + "','" + combo_area.SelectedItem + "'", con)
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

The error i get is:

> ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.6.24]You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: what exactly is the error you get?

Comment: The error i got is given above

Comment: For one, insert into should be uppercase and values too. Also depending on what version of mysql you are using, calling a query like that is depreciated. This I don't know but `OdbcCommand` does not look like Mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss the closing parenthesis for the values list:

```
Dim cmd1 As New OdbcCommand("insert into party values('" + pcode_txt.Text + "','" + Trim(UCase(name_txt.Text)) + "','" + Trim(UCase(addr_txt.Text)) + "','" + phone_txt.Text + "','" + combo_route.SelectedItem + "','" + combo_area.SelectedItem + "')", con)
```

My answer is perfectly fit to your question but as suggested in the comments have clear that string concatenation is not a dependable way to build queries.

A more secure solution is based on parameters. If possible avoid the creation of sql code in the application and rely upon server statements (stored procedures and/or views).

Comment: While this works, it is open to sql injection. This is a poor example with that in mind.

Comment: @OneFineDay 100% agree. the right implementation is a command with parameters or a stored procedure

Comment: Correct but my project manager asked me not to use parameters